# How to video capture device stop properly

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am working with c# project. so in here I used emguCV image processing library. this is my sample code to access to the web camera and stop. this code works but when I stop the video device it not stop properly.

```
 private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(capture==null){
            try
            {                    
                capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch(NullReferenceException ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if(capture!=null){
            if (captureInProgress)
            {
                btnStart.Text = "!Start";
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
            }
            else {
                btnStart.Text = "Stop";
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }
        }
        captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
    }
```

what I missed here. please help me.

Comment: Hi, What exactly do you mean its not stopped properly? If you want to release the device you will have to dispose of the capture variable itself.  capture.Dispose(); cheers

Comment: I added dispose() but after did that it shows exception. please can you show that thing using codes.@Chris

Comment: actually in here I am trying to access to the same web cam using Afroge library after stop above task(here I used emguCV library).Is this description clear enough? please give me a solution @Chris

Comment: actually after adding dispose() it show following exception -> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. @Chris

Comment: Ah this will be because while the dispose() will release the camera in c# terms I expect one of the opencv dlls is not. I use the method to pass the stream between use on forms without an issues. If you want to process the image using the Aforge library you could just save the grab image to a global image variable and process that. It won't effect processing time to much it will also allow Aforge and EMGU libraries to access the image. Unless the source of the stream is essential. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(capture==null){
            try
        {                    
            capture = new Capture();
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    if(capture!=null){
        if (captureInProgress)
        {
            btnStart.Text = "!Start";
            capture.Stop(); //you miss this
            Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
        }
        else {
            btnStart.Text = "Stop";
            capture.Start(); //you miss this
            Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
        }
    }
    captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
}
```

Comment: The answer would be better if you simply mentioned the line of code, where it belongs and more importantly, *why* it's necessary.

Comment: Look at the lines where he wrote the comment //you miss this

Comment: I use the Stop() method and remove the ProcessFrame event handler but I still get an exception thrown.